# Clear Server Cache on Browser Close Using ASP.NET

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

for a secure web application , How to clear an item in server Cache on Browser close.

Comment: @Roman:small correction to the question i posted.I need to remove a particular cache item from server.using javascript may be useful.

Comment: @Vikas - you could save some identifier in your session object and when it has timed out - you could know what piece of data you should remove. I can't how javascript may be helpful - because when you close your browser - the javascript won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the Session object and use it Session_End method to detect when the session is over and then do the cleanup.

More info about the session object you can find here - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ExploringSession.aspx

I'd use a small timeout so that the cache will clear almost immediately when the session is over. I might be wrong here - so if any one can help, it would be appreciated.

Good luck!